# В Vim/NeoVim не работают регистры [a-z]

Tags: vim

Я пытаюсь скопировать текст в регистр а командой "ayy  после проверяю командой :reg a Регистр а пустой. Что я делаю не так

Comment: а если просто попробовать сделать вставку - "ap ? сработает?

Comment: нет, не работает. Проблему я локализовал. У меня Manjaro KDE. И почемуто некоторые клавиши поменены местами. Например в английской раскладке " (двойная кавычка) на цифре 2, как в раскладке ЙЦУКЕН, а соответственно @ на ". Как будто это какая то модифицированная QWERTY. От самой клавы это не зависит (пробовал разные). А в VIM посылается сигнал @ и при нажатии SHIFT ' и при нажатии SHIFT 2. Сейчас пытаюсь разобраться, как это исправить. Если кто в курсе, подскажите.

Comment: может это просто немецкая раскладка или подобное.

Comment: Проблему решил: в настройках KDE клавиатуры поставил Английская Macintosh, а конфиге NeoVim убрал set langmap=!\\"№\\;%?*ёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЁЙЦУКЕHГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ;!@#$%&*`qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl\\;'zxcvbnm\\,.~QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\\"ZXCVBNM<> Которая отвечала за маппинг русских букв на английские в командном режиме. Без этого просто смена раскладки на Macintosh не работала. Может в этой строчке надо убрать только Э и ", попробую